# Issues with Armadillo sparse matrix initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, sparse-matrix, armadillo

**1.** I am trying to initialize a sparse matrix with Armadillo (on C++) but when I run the code

```
arma::umat locs;
arma::vec vals;


locs << 0 << 0 << arma::endr;
locs << 0 << 1 << arma::endr;
locs << 0 << 2 << arma::endr;

vals << 1.0;
vals << 2.0;
vals << 3.0;

std::cout << "locs =\n";
std::cout << locs;
std::cout << "vals =\n";
std::cout << vals;
```

the `locs` matrix and the `vals` vector keep only the last element read from a file. So, the output is

```
locs =
        0        2
vals =
   3.0000
```

Instead, when I launch this code

```
arma::umat locs;
arma::vec vals;

locs << 0 << 0 << arma::endr
     << 0 << 1 << arma::endr
     << 0 << 2 << arma::endr;

vals << 1.0
     << 2.0
     << 3.0;

std::cout << "locs =\n";
std::cout << locs;
std::cout << "vals =\n";
std::cout << vals;
```

I obtain

```
locs =
        0        0
        0        1
        0        2
vals =
   1.0000
   2.0000
   3.0000
```

and this is correct. But how can I use it to read values from a file?

**2.** [SOLVED, see comments] Moreover, when I call (on both the previous examples)

```
arma::sp_mat X(locs, vals);
```

I get the following error

```
error: SpMat::SpMat(): locations matrix must have two rows
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  SpMat::SpMat(): locations matrix must have two rows
```

I understand I am trying to allocate a dense vector, but this is just an example.
I am following the instructions reported on the Armadillo [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat).

Comment: What is the input you give to your program? Can you perhaps try to create a [mcve] with hardcoded values (instead of reading from `std::cin`) that replicates the problem, and [edit] your question to show it to us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well that is exactly the example reported [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#SpMat) and it works for me (the first part, not the second one when I am trying to initialize X). From my point of view, the one I code is a minimal example because I want to read values from a file.

Comment: What are the final dimensions of `locs` and `vals`? Is it possible both are empty because `n==0`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, I hope this way is clearer.

Comment: @Botje I hope my edit can help.

Comment: The documentation says that `arma::sp_mat` wants `locs` to have 2 rows, with each column representing a location. Your `locs` has 3 rows, with each row representing a location. The solution is to transpose your `locs`, like so: `arma::sp_mat X(locs.t(), vals);`

Comment: @hbrerkere Yes, thank you. I tried and it works. Now I think the documentation is wrong because the example does not specify to use the transposition.